# Cardview solo muestra el fondo en Android 10

Tags: android, android-studio, cardview

estoy aplicando un BackgroundColor a mi cardview, pero solo se muestra en Android 10, lo he probado en versiones anteriores y solo se muestra en transparente cuando en realidad el color de fondo es gris.

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="130dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="260dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/LightGrey"
    app:cardMaxElevation="0dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="80dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_camara_fotografica_20" />

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He resuelto el problema, lo hice de forma programada así:

```
 CardView card = view.findViewById(R.id.roundCardView);
 card.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#D3D3D3"));
 card.setMaxCardElevation((float) 0);
 card.setRadius((float) 50);
```

Comment: Probaste card_view:cardBackgroundColor, actualmente debemos usar esta propiedad.

Comment: si, pero no funciono, por eso tuve que hacerlo de forma programada.

Comment: Que raro , yo tengo apps que soportan desde API 16 y se muestra sin problema el fondo :-|

Comment: yo  actualice Android Studio a 4.1, crees que haya sido por eso??

Comment: No @Osdward , es independiente de hecho yo también tengo 4.1

Comment: crees que no me de problema usándolo de forma programada?

Comment: De ninguna manera @Osdward solo asegura que usas la clase: import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;

Answer (score 1):

Si usas AndroidX, debes usar `card_view:cardBackgroundColor` :

```
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        ...
        ...
        ...
        ...
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/detail_bkg_card"
        card_view:cardMaxElevation="0dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="80dp">
```

Revisa la documentación:

> Usa estas propiedades para personalizar la apariencia del widget
> CardView:
>
> • Para definir el radio de la esquina de tus diseños, usa el atributo
> **card_view:cardCornerRadius**.
>
> • Para definir el radio de la esquina de tu código, usa el método
> CardView.setRadius.
>
> • Para definir el color de fondo de una tarjeta, usa el atributo
> **card_view:cardBackgroundColor**.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/cardview